# Why am I getting an error while coding a binary search tree?

Tags: python, python-3.x, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I tried to code a binary search tree, but I'm stuck with an error saying int object has no attribute value. This implies that cur_node is being considered an int object. I can't seem to figure out why.
This was encountered while learning to code binary search trees from youtube.
PS: I'm new to Python so please do bear with me if it's silly.

```
class node:
    def __init__(self,value=None):
        self.value=value
        self.left_child=None
        self.right_child=None

class binary_search_tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root=None

    def insert(self,value):
        if self.root==None:
            self.root=value
        else:
            self._insert(value,self.root)

    def _insert(self,value,cur_node):
        if value<cur_node.value:
            if cur_node.left_child==None:
                cur_node.left_child=node(value)
            else:
                self._insert(value,cur_node.left_child)
        elif value>cur_node.value:
            if cur_node.right_child==None:
                cur_node.right_child=node(value)
            else:
                self._insert(value,cur_node.right_child)
        else:
            print("Value already in tree")

    def print_tree(self):
        if self.root!=None:
            self._print_tree(self.root)

    def _print_tree(self,cur_node):
        self._print_tree(cur_node.left_child)
        print(str(cur_node.value))
        self._print_tree(cur_node.right_child)

    def height(self):
        if self.root!=None:
            self._height(self.root,0)
        else:
            return 0

    def _height(self,cur_node,cur_height):
        if cur_node==None:
            return cur_height
        left=_height(cur_node.left_child,cur_height)
        right=_height(cur_node.right_child,cur_height)
        return max(left,right)

    def search(self,value):
        if(self.root!=None):
            self._search(self.root,value)
        else:
            return 0

    def _search(self,cur_node,value):
        if(cur_node.value==value):
            return 1
        elif value<cur_node.value and cur_node.left_child!=None:
            return self._search(cur_node.left_child,value)
        elif value>cur_node and cur_node.rightchild!=None:
            return self._search(cur_node.right_child,value)
        return 0

tree=binary_search_tree()
tree.insert(6)
tree.insert(8)
tree.insert(3)
tree.insert(17)
tree.insert(1)
tree.insert(4)

tree.print_tree()

tree.height()

tree.search(5)
tree.search(6)
```

Error Signature is:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/suprateem/PycharmProjects/TreeOfLIfe/TreeOfLife.py", line 70,
>   in
>
> ```
> tree.insert(8)
> ```
>
> File "/Users/suprateem/PycharmProjects/TreeOfLIfe/TreeOfLife.py",
>   line 15, in insert
>
> ```
> self._insert(value,self.root)
> ```
>
> File "/Users/suprateem/PycharmProjects/TreeOfLIfe/TreeOfLife.py",
>   line 18, in _insert
>
> ```
> if value<cur_node.value:
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'value'

Comment: You should learn how to use `pdb` and step through the program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, replace `if x!=None` with `if x`, and `if x==None` with `if not x`. `x!=None`/`x==None` is not pythonic. If you really need to check for `None` (not needed in your case), you should use `x is None`.

The error is in your insert method. You are not creating a `node` object for the root, but assigning the value to it. Change it in the following way:

```
def insert(self,value):
    if not self.root:
        self.root=node(value)
    else:
        self._insert(value,self.root)
```

You have also an error in the print method (you should check if the left/right subtree is not None):

```
def _print_tree(self,cur_node):
    if cur_node.left_child: self._print_tree(cur_node.left_child)
    print(str(cur_node.value))
    if cur_node.right_child: self._print_tree(cur_node.right_child)
```

Comment: ... and there are other errors as well (functions not always returning values, functions called but their results ignored).

Comment: Thanks for the help. Insertion and print works fine now. However, my _height function throws an error "referenced before assignment" on the line where left and right are being assigned. I looked it up, and usually it's a local-global issue, but in my case, I'm not getting exactly why.

Comment: PS: I have added "self." after the"=" in those statements (ie left=self._height....)

Comment: cannot reproduce your issue. I fixed your source in this way: https://pastebin.com/3bBVkPLv